# Webpage scroll goes beyond body and html tags

Tags: php, html, css

I'd like to know why I'm getting a huge empty space on this website under the footer: http://bigweb.uy/stanford/ .. The weird thing is that it goes beyond the html tag. I'm experienced and I don't use any fixed height for containers nor huge margins that may have caused this issue. This happens only on big screens. Do you know any css trick to make the overflow-y work properly on this website ?

Thank you all

Comment: Works fine on my iPhone. What browser/version and OS are you using?

Comment: add overflow:hidden to html tag

Comment: it gets normal after loading all contents

Comment: I'm using Google Chrome and the issue happens in Mozilla as well. @StephenR

Comment: If I add overflow:hidden to html tag, I can't see the last part of the website (latest news and footer) @FridayAmeh

Comment: @jasinthpremkumar , are you looking at the website on a desktop screen ? It does not get normal even after loading all elements ..

Comment: can you post your code

Comment: @BigWebUy do as frday ameh told it solves your proble

Comment: Adding overflow:hidden to the html tag partially solves the problem .. when I do that I don't see the empty space , but I can't see the footer, and in mobile devices I can't scroll down to see any of the content. I've also added a div with "clear:both" style under the footer as a desperate attempt to solve the problem but I still can't see it on desktop.. my code is calling each part od the website separately, and it's dynamic (generates the content based on what's in the database managed by a CMS made in PHP). I don't think it will help at all.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve the problem by removing the "position:absolute" from the .tab-panel element. I have no clue why this was causing my problem , but I was finally able to solve it that way. Thank you all for your time !

Comment: You should mark this as the answer so the question is closed